# Solving an equation $x^{22}\equiv2 \bmod 23$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

I have an abstract algebra problem which I am unable to solve.

> The problem is, if $x^{22}\equiv2 \bmod 23$, then $x$ has how many solutions?
>
> Source: TIFR Graduate School Admissions Entrance Test Maths 2011 [TIFR GS-2011, Q7]

Please explain me.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  It's a finite problem...worst case, you just have to look at $x = 0,1,..., 22$.  Or it might help to look up the Little Fermat Theorem.

Comment: There are zero solutions, since $x^{22}\equiv 1 \bmod 23$ for all $x$ corpime to $p=23$ by Fermat.

Comment: @DietrichBurde not for all $x$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde It is  $x^{22}\equiv2 \bmod 23$. How can I apply Fermate's little theorem here? please explain.

Comment: You expect a response 2 years later?  Okay.  $23$ is prime.  So if $(x,23)$ are coprime $x^{22}\equiv 1 \mod 23$.  If $x$ is not comprime to $23$, $x$ is a multiple of $23$.  So $x^{22} \equiv 1 \mod 23$ if $x$ is not a multiple of $23$ and $x^22 \equiv 0 \mod 23$ if $x$ is a multiple of $23$.